# What does the dummy value mean?

Tags: c

Input the Employee no and the Basic Salary of the Employees in an organization ending with the dummy value -999  for  Employee no  and count the number Employees whose Basic Salary  >=5000.

Comment: [sentinel value?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)

Comment: @yano you are hitting on all 8-cylinders and your crystal-ball is clear as a bell tonight.

Answer (score 0):

As used here, a *dummy value* is different than a regular value, and used to select an organization.  It may signify test data.

In production software, you don't want to assign meaning to a partial value of a field.  As this implies that any changes to the value of a field may break your software unexpectedly.  Instead create a new dedicated field (`boolean is_test_data`).